# POST request using JSON and Web API?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I have two models: Child and Location. They have a relationship. This is what Location looks like:

```
public class Location {
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public float Latitude { get; set; }
    public float Longitude { get; set; }
    public float Accuracy { get; set; }
    public DateTime ReportTime { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual Child Child { get; set; }
}
```

`

The Child model looks along those lines (FirstName, LastName, etc.) and has a reference to `ICollection<Location> Locations`.

My controller looks like this:

```
[ResponseType(typeof(Location))]
        public IHttpActionResult PostLocation([FromBody] Location location)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            db.Locations.Add(location);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = location.Id }, location);
        }
```

When POSTing data using JSON from a mobile device, ideally I would like to pass the Child's ID value instead of the entire Child object. However, every time when inspecting the incoming `Location` object, the `child` property is set to `null`. I have tried the following JSONs:

```
{
    "Latitude": 43.63434,
    "Longitude": -92.12345,
    "Accuracy": 13,
    "ReportTime": "2016-05-11T23:29:30.87",
    "Child": {
        "Id": 3
    }
}
```

and

```
{
    "Latitude": 43.63434,
    "Longitude": -92.12345,
    "Accuracy": 13,
    "ReportTime": "2016-05-11T23:29:30.87",
    "Child": 3
}
```

I have even tried to pass an entire `Child` object (copy/pasted what I got from my own details GET ApiController), but the child is still set to null.

I am pretty new to ASP.NET and especially Web API so I'd appreciate any help. How can I instruct the WebAPI to at least parse the ID part of the Child object?

I know that technically I could solve this by adding another property to the Location model, `int ChildId` - but I was wondering if there was a more elegant solution (there are quite a few models associated with `Child`).

Thank you!

Comment: I see you are using a complex type (Location). Try either changing FromBody to FromUri. If it doesn't work, try removing it. I had this issue earlier today when the JSON object i POSTed was null. For reference on param binding http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api

Comment: Remove `[JsonIgnore]` from the `Child` property. But since your only posting one property of `Child`, you should be creating a view model containing only those properties you need (and it would have property `int ChildId` rather that `Child Child`)

Answer (score 0):

Change the property name of Child to other name. eg.

```
public virtual Child ChildProp { get; set; }
```

And your Json data:

```
{
"Latitude": 43.63434,
"Longitude": -92.12345,
"Accuracy": 13,
"ReportTime": "2016-05-11T23:29:30.87",
"ChildProp": {
    "Id": 3
    }
}
```